# Php what does <<< mean?

Tags: php, syntax

In the following code from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php what does the <<< symbol mean?

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
   // invalid property declarations:
   public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
   public $var2 = <<<EOD
hello world
EOD;
   public $var3 = 1+2;
   public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
   public $var5 = $myVar;

   // valid property declarations:
   public $var6 = myConstant;
   public $var7 = array(true, false);

   // This is allowed only in PHP 5.3.0 and later.
   public $var8 = <<<'EOD'
hello world
EOD;
}
?>
```

Comment: As posted, the code is incorrect - the `EOD;` lines are not allowed to be indented. Note that the page you linked to does not have that portion indented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and can be used to assign string values.

Comment: What are the benefits of assigning strings in this fashion?

Comment: For 1 is that you do not have to worry about new line operators.

Answer (score 4):

A string in [Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 3):

It's just another way to define a String (Newdoc/Heredoc syntax) - [Manual - String](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)